# How to change a single line in multiple files

Tags: sed, regular-expression, php

I have ~750 .php files in the same directory that contain the line

```
include("path/to/file.php");
```

I would like to change this line in **every** file to

```
require_once("path/to/file.php");
```

What would be an efficient method to do so? So far I have tried the following Sed command with no luck:

```
sed 's#include("path/to/file.php");#require_once("path/to/file.php");#' *.php
```

Comment: Your command looks correct, but you need to add `-i` option to sed in order to change files in place.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find /path/to/the/directory -type f -exec sed -i 's/include\(.*\)/require_once\1/' {} +
```

This will find all the files in the given directory and replace the lines "include("path/to/file.php");" of each file to "require_once("path/to/file.php");".